# Duplicating an (st) terminal

Tags: suckless-terminal

I frequently want to duplicate my terminal from whatever directory I am in. I use the command `(/bin/sh -c st cd $PWD &; read -)`, but this requires me to press enter before I can continue in the original terminal. Can I do something so I can immediately type the next command in my original terminal? I'd rather not install a terminal multiplexer for something as trivial as this.

Comment: What do you actually mean by "duplicate"? Can't you just start `st &`, or does that take you to another directory than the current?

Comment: @Kusalananda I mean opening another terminal in the same directory. `st &` starts in `$HOME`

Comment: @user388557 there is a patch[0] for `st` which allows you to open a new `st` in current working directory using a key combination. [0]https://st.suckless.org/patches/newterm/

Comment: I am using [xcwd](https://github.com/schischi/xcwd) for this. For example `st -e /bin/dash -c "cd $(xcwd);exec zsh"`